# how to stop progress bar Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to create HTML5+CSS3 and jQuery progress bar which let's say should start loading and stop for example at 10% of it's width but I manage to create only to count the MAX value of HTML which in my case is 10%.

Here is picture how the progressBar should look like when finish with loading:

[image: Pic Example]

Can someone give me some advice where is my mistake or lead me to some simple solution?

This is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <progress min="0 " value="0" max="10" id="firstProgressBar"></progress>
  <span class="firstProgress">0%</span>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var firstProgressBar = $('#firstProgressBar'),
    max = firstProgressBar.attr('max'),
    value = firstProgressBar.val(),
    time = (500/max)*10;

function firstLoading(){
    value+=1;
    var addValue = firstProgressBar.val(value);

    $('.firstProgress').html(value + '%');

    if ( value == max ) {
        clearInterval(animate);
    }

};

var animate = setInterval(function(){
    firstLoading();
}, time);
```

Here is my full code as Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ekbyrt5/

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your jsfiddle. Main problem was jsfiddle didn't load jQuery (maybe it was a mistaken fiddle version). Hope this helps.

When **progress value is max, progress bar is full**. If you want to stop at 10%, you must divide max value of progress by 10 as maximum value to be set on your progress bar.

*Note: I've set max at 100 just to show a progress from 1 to 10%.*

```js
var firstProgressBar = $('#firstProgressBar'),
  max = firstProgressBar.attr('max') / 10,
  value = firstProgressBar.val(),
  time = (500 / max) * 10;

function firstLoading() {
  value += 1;
  var addValue = firstProgressBar.val(value);

  $('.firstProgress').html(value + '%');

  if (value >= max) {
    clearInterval(animate);
  }

};

var animate = setInterval(function() {
  firstLoading();
}, time);
```

```css
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  width: 248px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <progress min="0 " value="0" max="100" id="firstProgressBar"></progress>
  <span class="firstProgress">0%</span>
</form>
```